# AngularJS limitBy depending on if-clause

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to implement the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:item.limitOfItems track by $index">
```

However, not every item has item.limitOfItems defined. If it's not defined it doesn't run the ng-repeat at all. Therefor I'm search for a way to first check if this item has `item.limitOfItems` defined and if so, use the limitTo function.

**Update** : I don't want the li-element to not render if the property (limitOfItems) is not available.

I've found a way to fix the problem I was having by doing the following:
Maybe I've phrased my question wrong but I don't want that the

-element doesn't render when this property (limitOfItems) is not provided.

I've found a way to make it work like I want to:

```
<li ng-repeat="includedItem in ::currentItem.includedItems |limitTo: (currentItem.limitOfIncludedItems || 5) track by $index" class="whatsIncludedItem">
```

However, if I assign the static 5 to a scope variable in my controller, it doesn't work anymore. Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this doesn't really make sense.  the `limitTo` function takes a singular value to limit the number of elements iterated by `ng-repeat`.  it doesn't apply the filter to each row, so specifying a value from a row in the array wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you missunderstood the limitTo-filter. it says that the first/last x numbers of the array will be taken to repeat them.
In your case it will take the first x entries of items.

[have a look to this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you need to filter the undefined first you need to do this by creating your custom filter and then limitTo

HTML Sample

```
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="row in friends |myFilter|limitTo:1,2 ">{{row.name}}</li>
<ul>
```

Js App and filter creation

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(items) {                                     

            return items.filter(function(item){ return item.limitOfItems !== undefined; });
        }
    });

function myCtrl($scope)
{    
    $scope.friends = [
      {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
    ];
}

myApp.controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);
```